# Funny and annoying excel issue with IP the address

Tags: excel, vba

so here is my problem. When I type 10.100.100.10 in excel, it is perfectly fine. If I type 10.100.100.100 or any other number with more digits excel automatically gets rid of the dots. I can solve this by replacing the cell formats to text. But this leads me to another problem. I have to add dots again once after the format change and that is not very easy due to the nature of the files that I work with. Even if I do that, when I try to find/replace for example 10.100.100 with 10.100.900 , all the dots get removed again.

note: I tried to fix the cell format when replacing, that did not work.
note 2: My pc and excel are 64 bits.

Thanks!

Comment: putting a ' bevore the ip should solve the problem

Comment: You might update your question and tell people which country you are in (I guess you are in Turkey) and this helps people understand that your thousands separator is a `.` and not a `,` like in English-speaking countries. Agree with comment from @GEnGEr to use a `'` before the input, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA to autotoggle the thousands separator.

Open VBA editor by ALT + F11
Doubleclick on ThisWorkbook in project window on the left.
In the textwindow that opens paste this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With Application
        .UseSystemSeparators = True
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application
        .ThousandsSeparator = ","
        .UseSystemSeparators = False
    End With

End Sub
```

This will make "," a thousands separator for Excel when you open the workbook and reset it to "default" when you close.
Keep in mind that if you have two workbooks open this may cause conflicts on the other workbook, or if Excel by some reason crashes.
If it does crash, reopen this workbook and close it again (unless you need to keep working with it).
The important thing to remember is that the workbook needs to be closed to reset the settings of Excel.

EDIT; after you added the code you need to save the file as and Excel file with macrocode (can't remember the correct name of it) and close and reopen it.

Comment: it should resolve the issue. I don't see any reason why not. ++

Comment: macro enabled file is .xlsm :) 2007 onwards.

Comment: Thanks! I'm forced against my will to use Excel in Swedish at work, so most of my workhours are spent on trying to figure out what the function I know by heart is called in swedish. You may think it's logic, but you are wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are copy and pasting this ID adress you should press crtl + w so that Excel is getting the value of the cell and not the cell out of the other documents. This was helping by Errors with numbers which I got formatted to Dates.

If you are typing in the adress manually you should Format the whole column or row before you are inserting the IP- Adress this may help.

The last possibility is to write a macro which is automatically started if something in the column is changed and then it should insert the dots for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys putting a ' before the number worked as a charm.